# Redimensionar DIV de acordo com tamanho do menu

Tags: html, css3, front-end, div, layout-responsivo

Coloquei o código html + css dentro de um JSFiddle para ajudar na visualização do problema.

O que eu preciso fazer é que a div com nome de "kk" se redimensione de acordo com o tamanho do menu, por ex: se o menu estiver minimizado ele deve ter o tamanho total com o menu minimizado, se o usuario passar o mouse em cima do menu e o menu expandir a div teria que ser "empurrada" para a direita e fazer com que o menu não sobreponha a div.

https://jsfiddle.net/edbngqtL/

```css
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css);
}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300);
.fa-2x {
font-size: 2em;
}
.fa {
position: relative;
display: table-cell;
width: 60px;
height: 36px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size:20px;
}


.main-menu:hover,nav.main-menu.expanded {
width:250px;
overflow:visible;
}

.main-menu {
background:#212121;
border-right:1px solid #e5e5e5;
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
height:100%;
left:0;
width:60px;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-transition:width .05s linear;
transition:width .05s linear;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
z-index:1000;
}

.main-menu>ul {
margin:7px 0;
}

.main-menu li {
position:relative;
display:block;
width:250px;
}

.main-menu li>a {
position:relative;
display:table;
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:0;
color:#999;
 font-family: arial;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-webkit-transition:all .1s linear;
transition:all .1s linear;
  
}

.main-menu .nav-icon {
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
width:60px;
height:36px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
font-size:18px;
}

.main-menu .nav-text {
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
width:190px;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

.main-menu>ul.logout {
position:absolute;
left:0;
bottom:0;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover {
overflow-y:hidden;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover:hover {
overflow-y:auto;
overflow:visible;
}

a:hover,a:focus {
text-decoration:none;
}

nav {
-webkit-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
-o-user-select:none;
user-select:none;
}

nav ul,nav li {
outline:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.main-menu li:hover>a,nav.main-menu li.active>a,.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,.dropdown-menu>.active>a,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus,.no-touch .dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li:hover a,.dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li.active a {
color:#fff;
background-color:#5fa2db;
}
.area {
float: left;
background: #e2e2e2;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Titillium WebLight'), local('TitilliumWeb-Light'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/titilliumweb/v2/anMUvcNT0H1YN4FII8wpr24bNCNEoFTpS2BTjF6FB5E.woff) format('woff');
}

.kk {
  border: 3px solid red;
  background-color:red;
  
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    
        
 
  </head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="i.css">
  <body><div class="area"></div>
    <nav class="main-menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://justinfarrow.com">
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Dashboard
                        </span>
                    </a>
                  
                </li>
                <li class="has-subnav">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Stars Components
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    
                </li>
                <li class="has-subnav">
                    <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Forms
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    
                </li>
                <li class="has-subnav">
                    <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-folder-open fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Pages
                        </span>
                    </a>
                   
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Graphs and Statistics
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-font fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                           Quotes
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-table fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Tables
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Maps
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-info fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Documentation
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="logout">
                <li>
                   <a href="#">
                         <i class="fa fa-power-off fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Logout
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>  
            </ul>
        </nav>
    <div class="kk">
        KKK Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem cupiditate dolore repellendus magnam ratione molestias hic deserunt enim harum at sequi fugit, expedita repudiandae similique quasi tempore, possimus alias magni!
    </div>
    
  </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara vc tem que fazer uns ajustes simples, como vc tem a estrutura no HTML `<nav> + <div kk>` fica fácil fazer isso no CSS usando `nav:hover + .kk { }`

O que vc precisa fazer é colocar um `translateX()` na `div.kk` e ao mesmo tempo diminuir do `width` esse valor do `translate` mais a margem, para isso usei `width: calc(100% - 256px)`, assim não vai dar *scroll* horizontal na sua página

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```css
@import url(https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css);


@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300);

.fa-2x {
    font-size: 2em;
}

.fa {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 60px;
    height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 20px;
}


.main-menu:hover,
nav.main-menu.expanded {
    width: 250px;
    overflow: visible;
}

.main-menu {
    background: #212121;
    border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: width .05s linear;
    transition: width .05s linear;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
    z-index: 1000;
}

.main-menu > ul {
    margin: 7px 0;
}

.main-menu li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
}

.main-menu li > a {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    color: #999;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
    -webkit-transition: all .1s linear;
    transition: all .1s linear;

}

.main-menu .nav-icon {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 60px;
    height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.main-menu .nav-text {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 190px;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

.main-menu > ul.logout {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover:hover {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

nav ul,
nav li {
    outline: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-menu li:hover > a,
nav.main-menu li.active > a,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus,
.no-touch .dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li:hover a,
.dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li.active a {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5fa2db;
}

.area {
    float: left;
    background: #e2e2e2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Titillium Web';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: local('Titillium WebLight'), local('TitilliumWeb-Light'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/titilliumweb/v2/anMUvcNT0H1YN4FII8wpr24bNCNEoFTpS2BTjF6FB5E.woff) format('woff');
}

.kk {
    border: 3px solid red;
    background-color: red;

}

/* Aqui os ajustes de CSS */
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

.kk {
    margin-left: 60px;
    transition: all 0.05ms; 
}

nav:hover + .kk {
    transform: translateX(190px);
    width: calc(100% - 256px);
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://justinfarrow.com">
                <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                <span class="nav-text">
                    Dashboard
                </span>
            </a>

        </li>
        <li class="has-subnav">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i>
                <span class="nav-text">
                    Stars Components
                </span>
            </a>

        </li>
        <li class="has-subnav">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i>
                <span class="nav-text">
                    Forms
                </span>
            </a>

        </li>
        <li class="has-subnav">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-folder-open fa-2x"></i>
                <span class="nav-text">
                    Pages
                </span>
            </a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-2x"></i>
                <span class="nav-text">
                    Graphs and Statistics
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-font fa-2x"></i>
                <span class="nav-text">
                    Quotes
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-table fa-2x"></i>
                <span class="nav-text">
                    Tables
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x"></i>
                <span class="nav-text">
                    Maps
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-info fa-2x"></i>
                <span class="nav-text">
                    Documentation
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="logout">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-power-off fa-2x"></i>
                <span class="nav-text">
                    Logout
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="kk">
    KKK Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem cupiditate dolore repellendus magnam ratione molestias hic deserunt enim harum at sequi fugit, expedita repudiandae similique quasi tempore, possimus alias magni!
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, era exatamente o que precisava :)!

Comment: @FernandoMunhoz legal jovem, que bom que resolveu ai!